# statsmodels adfuller maxlag bug or feature?

Tags: python

I have the following code that utilizes statsmodels' adfuller.

```py
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
data = np.asarray ([3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 10, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 10, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 10, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 10, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 10, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 10, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 10, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 10, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 10, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 10])

results = adfuller(data, regression='n', maxlag=20, autolag="aic")
print (results)
```

The result was not what I expected (calculated manually).  So, I did a bit of investigation.

If you run the code through pdb and break at line 133 of stattools.py ( https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/tsa/stattools.py )

Then run the following check k_constant flag

```py
for r in results: print ("r: %d, %.15g" % (r, results[r].k_constant))
```

The output is the following:

```
r: 1, 0
r: 2, 0
r: 3, 0
r: 4, 0
r: 5, 0
r: 6, 0
r: 7, 0
r: 8, 0
r: 9, 0
r: 10, 0
r: 11, 0
r: 12, 0
r: 13, 1
r: 14, 1
r: 15, 1
r: 16, 1
r: 17, 1
r: 18, 1
r: 19, 1
r: 20, 1
r: 21, 1
```

Note that I ran adfuller with regression being 'n', that is, there should be no added intercept (constant).  This is the case for the first 12 lags.  Mysteriously, the 13th lag had k_constant set to 1, indicating having intercept constant column.

I found out that the issue here is that adfuller runs OLS which automatically detects whether or not there is a constant.  In data.py ( https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/base/data.py ) line 172 (check_implicit is true and hasconst is None), it uses the approach of adding a const column (all ones) and then checking the rank, vs the rank before to check if there is an implicit constant column.  This resulted in k_constant being set to 1.  This is despite the fact that the min / max values for all the columns are different.  While the rank comparison rationale makes sense, but it occurs to me that it is prone to precision issues.

Because of k_constant is changed from 0 to 1, all the degrees of freedom calculations are drastically changed.  That in turn changed a number of stats values associated with the linear model.

The change in stats led to subsequent changes in stats values computed.  The bestlag picked is affected.  The final iteration of calculation for the given lag is different as well.

My question is: is this a bug or feature for statsmodels' adfuller?

If this is intended, can somebody explain the rationale?